# Path of file in shared project

Tags: file, xamarin.forms, io

I have a TXT file (*MyFile.txt*) in my shared project which I try to read with `File.ReadAllLines()`

I tried both `File.ReadAllLines("MyFile.txt")` and `File.ReadAllLines("MyApp\MyFile.txt")`
and they return:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file

and

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path

respectively.

Which is the correct path?

Comment: How are you including a file in your shared project!  What is its build action?  You typically cannot include files in libraries unless they are embedded resources

Comment: I am assuming you are using Visual Studio, it could be the case if you are running it as administrator.

Comment: @Jason I have set both no build action and "Resource". No difference. Same errors.

Comment: @user10191234 Running VS with administrator rights or without makes no difference.

Comment: A Resource is not a file and does not have a file path.  There are numerous existing questions about reading resources in C#

Comment: I also set it to "Embedded resource". Still getting the same errors.

Comment: As I noted before, resources are not files and cannot be read using File apis.  See the linked question for an example of how to read a resource